# How do I stop my cat inappropriately urinating and the other litter box guarding?

Tags: cats, behavior, urination

I adopted two kittens three months ago, they've since become a bonded pair.They were both using the litter boxes with no issue. After the first month my more timid cat began inappropriately urinating in other parts of the apartment, first it was the base of the cat tower and now its the tile floor in the entrance way near our front door.
I have multiple litter boxes, clean them every day, have tried different types of litter and even moved one of the litter boxes in the hallway where the timid cat seems to prefer urinating. He still won't use the litter box to urinate. I've tried using 'pet safe sprays' on the problem area to deter him, have tried positive reinforcement whenever I see him leave the litter box. Have moved around their food bowls all to no avail. I have noticed that my more dominant cat will run towards either litter box as soon as he hears the other using it and have tried my best to distract him, but obviously can't monitor the behaviour when I'm not at home.

Does anyone have any suggestions that might work?

That isn't:

separating the cats (they're very co-dependent on the other and get upset when they can't find each other)

Adding more litter boxes - there are only so many litter boxes one can fit in an apartment in different locations.

Moving their food bowls

Spraying citrus based cleaner

Using sticky tape

Changing the litter (have tried)

Any suggestions on anything I haven't tried will be most appreciated!

Comment: You write that the timid cat is male. Is he actually urinating (puddle in the floor) or spraying (urine on vertical surfaces)? If he's spraying, you need to get him neutered as quickly as possible to have any chance of this behavior stopping.

Comment: They're both male and neutered and actual urinating

Comment: Have you been to the vet yet? Most of the time, inappropriate urination is a sign of a health problem. Additionally, have you tried *appropriate* cleaners (enzymatic, not "household citrus-based")? Pet cleaners will break down the urine; without doing that, even if you can't smell it, your cats still will, and will continue to urinate in that location.

Comment: If this is indeed a litter box aggression issue, additional positive reinforcement on the litter box dominant cat might work. Essentially, you want the dominant cat to form a positive connection to the timid cat urinating in peace. We have done this successfully with food bowl dominance, with a special treat that is only given when the dominant cat does not disrupt the others eating. Either way, you should check with the vet first, as AllisonC said these issues very often have underlying medical causes.

Comment: What kind of litter box do you have?  I've had one cat that only would use boxes that have a cover (one assumes for privacy).  I've had another cat who wouldn't climb over a lip to use a box (he ended up using a pile of litter on a flat tray - to this day I don't know why this was).  Can you try covering a litter tray with a large box that has an opening on one side and see if the timid cat uses that?